# vdpauinfo: display: :0.0 screen: 0 Error creating VDPAU device: 1

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, vdpau

New to this community.
I hope that someone can help me with the below.
I am at the point that I need to get vdpau to work to offload the CPU. No luck.

Last week my new GT610 nvidia card arrived - I had an ever so small hope that my current GT220 had a fault - installed it, and I still cannot get vdpau to work. Hence the GT220 is back in its position.

What I mean is that after installing vdpauinfo the command: `~$ vdpauinfo` gives:

> display: :0.0
>   screen: 0 Error creating VDPAU device: 1

The motherboard is a Gigabyte H55M-UD2H with on-board video controller and HDMI connector which I have disabled in the BIOS using the PEG setting. (according to the BIOS this would mean that it will select an external card over the on-board one).
I installed Ubuntu 13.04 since I had that on DVD, and downloaded and applied all the updates that came through. Checking the video driver it indicated nouveau - which is "as expected".
Upon the prompt to move to 13.10 I did so.
I then used the "settings" option right top corner to install the nvidia drivers - I believe I picked the top one which should include the VDPAU capbility.
After that finished I stopped the X-server, opened a terminal session and generated a new Xconf file and then tried to start the X-server again. This failed and it required a hard reboot.
Machine came back-up. I installed vdpauinfo using apt-get.
Then I executed "vdpauinfo" with the result as listed above.Error creating VDPAU device: 1"
I have tried this numerous times over the last releases, probably as far back as 10.10, and it never worked.
I have trawled the web pages and followed clues and advice to no avail, this is the last piece of the puzzle to have my Ubuntu based mediacentre which works like a dream apart from this bit.

Any help in resolving this or arriving at the point why this cannot work for me is much appreciated.

snippet from sudo lshw output:

```
test-iv-medcntr
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: H55M-UD2H ()
    vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-1C6F65825E1D
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: H55M-UD2H
       vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       version: x.x
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Award Software International, Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: F11
          date: 08/20/2010
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU        G6950  @ 2.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU
          slot: Socket 1156
          size: 1197MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm popcnt lahf_lm arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
        *-cache:0
             ***[data removed]***
        *-cache:1
             ***[data removed]***
     *-memory
          ***[data removed]***
        *-bank:0
             ***[data removed]***
        *-bank:1
             ***[data removed]***
        *-bank:2
             ***[data removed]***
        *-bank:3
             ***[data removed]***
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 12
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 12
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:f9000000-faffffff ioport:d0000000(size=536870912)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GT216 [GeForce GT 220]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ee000000-efffffff ioport:bf00(size=128) memory:e0000000-e007ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:faffc000-faffffff
        ***[data removed]***
```

For completeness I also include snippets from the "Xorg.0.log"

snippets from Xorg.0.log

```
[    16.220] 
X.Org X Server 1.14.5
Release Date: 2013-12-12
[    16.220] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    16.220] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    16.220] Current Operating System: Linux TEST-IV-MEDCNTR 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64
[    16.220] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic root=UUID=32995062-eaef-4392-a77a-3fcf80fa543c ro quiet splash
[    16.220] Build Date: 17 December 2013  10:06:15AM
[    16.220] xorg-server 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    16.220] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    16.220]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    16.220] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    16.220] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Feb  9 13:27:51 2014
[    16.220] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    16.220] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    16.241] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    16.241] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    16.241] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    16.241] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    16.241] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    16.241] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    16.241] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    16.241] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    16.241] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    16.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    16.241]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    16.241]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    16.241]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    16.241]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    16.241]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.241] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    16.241] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    16.241] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    16.241] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    16.241] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    16.241] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f131dcd7d20
[    16.241] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    16.241]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    16.241]    X.Org Video Driver: 14.1
[    16.241]    X.Org XInput driver : 19.1
[    16.241]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[    16.243] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0a20:0000:0000 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf9000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xee000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000bf00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    16.243] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    16.243] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    16.243] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    16.243] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    16.243] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    16.243] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    16.243] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    16.275] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    17.365] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.365]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 0.5.1
[    17.365]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    17.365] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    17.365] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    17.487] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    17.487]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    17.487]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    17.487] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:46:57 PDT 2013
[    17.487] Loading extension GLX
[    17.487] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    17.487] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    17.558] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    17.558]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    17.558]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    17.565] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:28:14 PDT 2013
[    17.565] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    17.571] (++) using VT number 7

[    17.573] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    17.573] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    17.579] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    17.580] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.580]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[    17.580]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    17.580] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    17.580] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    17.580] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    17.588] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.588]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[    17.588]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    17.588] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    17.588] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    17.588] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    17.598] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    17.598] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    17.598] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    17.598] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    17.598] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    18.544] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    18.544] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    18.546] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 220 (GT216) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    18.546] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[    18.546] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.16.27.00.02
[    18.546] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    18.546] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GT 220 at PCI:1:0:0
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0):     SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (connected)
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal Single Link TMDS
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0): SAMSUNG (DFP-1): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    18.548] (--) NVIDIA(0): SAMSUNG (DFP-1): Internal Single Link TMDS
[    18.548] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    18.548] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    18.548] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    18.555] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    18.555] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    18.555] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    18.555] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    18.555] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    18.555] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[    18.555] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[    18.581] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (304, 304); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    18.581] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    18.581] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    18.581] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[    18.585] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[    18.622] Loading extension NV-GLX
[    18.650] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    18.650] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    18.650] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    18.651] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    18.660] Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    18.660] Loading extension XINERAMA
[    18.660] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    18.660] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    18.660] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    18.660] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    18.660] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    18.660] (--) RandR disabled
[    18.664] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    18.664] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    18.696] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
***[data removed]***
[    18.705] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    18.705] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.705] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.705] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    18.706] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event13)
[    18.706] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.706] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.706] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event14)
[    18.706] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.706] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.706] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event15)
[    18.706] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.706] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.706] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event16)
[    18.706] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.706] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.707] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Pulse-Eight USB-CEC Adapter (/dev/input/event2)
***[data removed]***
[    18.708] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    18.709] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.709] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.709] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line (/dev/input/event10)
[    18.709] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.709] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.709] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Front Mic (/dev/input/event11)
[    18.709] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.709] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.709] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Rear Mic (/dev/input/event12)
[    18.709] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.709] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.709] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Front Headphone (/dev/input/event5)
[    18.709] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.709] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.709] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line Out Side (/dev/input/event6)
[    18.709] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.709] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event7)
[    18.710] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.710] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event8)
[    18.710] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.710] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line Out Front (/dev/input/event9)
[    18.710] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.710] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    20.181] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    20.181] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    20.181] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    20.181] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    20.181] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    21.743] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    21.743] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    21.743] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    21.743] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    21.743] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    30.475] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    30.475] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    30.475] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    30.475] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    30.475] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    30.659] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    30.743] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    30.743] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    30.743] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    30.743] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    30.743] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    31.261] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    31.261] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    31.261] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    31.261] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    31.261] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    33.024] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B8CD4FE5A1833D7AB4B402792017A55B628FCF2D.xkm
[    33.032] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B8CD4FE5A1833D7AB4B402792017A55B628FCF2D.xkm
[    33.172] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    33.172] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    33.172] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    33.172] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    33.172] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    34.933] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-07844D531AFAE8C05AD2DE44539CA82502952248.xkm
[    53.638] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    53.638] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    53.638] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    53.638] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    53.638] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[  1274.427] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (SAMSUNG (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[  1274.427] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[  1274.427] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[  1274.427] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device SAMSUNG (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[  1274.427] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[  3884.333] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Close
[  3884.333] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3884.333] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Close
[  3884.333] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3884.333] (II) evdev: Pulse-Eight USB-CEC Adapter: Close
[  3884.333] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3884.333] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  3884.333] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3884.333] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  3884.333] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3884.688] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

As I said looking for any thoughts on how to progress.
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

That error is displayed because you ran "vdpauinfo" with "sudo". Try again with "vdpauinfo" without "sudo".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response tried "vdpauinfo" as opposed to "sudo vdpauinfo", however the result is the same.